# Diodes in parallel

Tags: diodes, parallel

I need to protect about 5A @ 6V from something stupid like my revering the battery wires when connecting them to the circuit. I thought that I could use 5x 1A diodes in parallel, but it seems that I will have thermal runaway.

Is this an option or does someone else know of a better way to protect a circuit from reverse voltage?

Comment: http://www.wa0itp.com/revpro.html : a big list of reverse voltage protection strategies.

Comment: ive heard of a way to use a p-channel MOSFET for reverse protection

Comment: @skyler: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva139/slva139.pdf http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Reverse-Batery-Protection-Rev2.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b418872b2614&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b41887722615&ack=t

Answer (score 5):

It's never recommended to parallel diodes unless they're on the same die (i.e. a double diode inside a single TO-220 or TO-247 package) since you can never guarantee that they'll share the current.

A better option is a MOSFET with an 'ideal diode' OR-ing controller. These devices detect body diode conduction, then turn the MOSFET on so that you don't burn power in the body diode. They also abort reverse current (if there's a fault after the MOSFET is on) and won't conduct reverse polarity. [TI](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=1644&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T&paramCriteria=no&DCMP=hpa_pmp_linepower&HQS=Other+OT+oring-sbd), [Linear Technology](http://www.linear.com/products/powerpath_controllers_%2a_ideal_diodes) and others have a wide assortment of these types of controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a p-channel MOSFET for reverse protection. It is much more efficient, does not drain a lot of heat, and less power is wasted. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrB-FPcv1Dc) is a YouTube video talking about it's efficiency, and following is a picture of a schematic. Diodes aren't horrible though,and they are pretty efficient compared to the old selenium rectifiers or vacuum tubes or crystal rectifiers. For the MOSFET, an IRFp450 should suit your needs if you want to do the MOSFET strategy. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't fully understand; but couldn't you simply place a single diode in series with the battery? The graph below is the voltage vs. current relationship of a diode.

Diodes don't "Breakdown" until the 70-100 volt range. So even if you were to accidentally reverse the voltage with 6 volts, the current through the diode would be very close to zero. In which case you'd be safe.

[image]

Comment: The idea is that the diode is placed across the power rails, but reversed in *normal* operation when the polarity is correct. When the battery is reversed, the diode becomes forward-biased and provides an easier path for the current. OP is trying to use multiple diodes because a single one doesn't have the current rating: it will just melt, open, and leave the circuit unprotected.

Comment: That method does make sense; most the current will travel through the diode and not through OP's load circuit. 5 amps would damage the semiconductor when forward biased.

Comment: @Kaz It would work if there were a fusible link that melts before the diode does and disconnects the battery, but you have to make sure the diode sinks more current than the device